# how to use substring and concat operation together

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to run a query but it gives me error on concat of missing expression. i am building an insert query where one columne values are inserted from another table by concatenating the two columns and getting first letter from first column and whole value from second column. 
Heres my query.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO MSGG_USER (USERNAME)
SELECT substr (GIVEN_NAME, 1,1)GIVEN_NAME, || '' || SURNAME
FROM MSGG_PEOPLE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second mention of `GIVEN_NAME`, just concatenate the call to `SUBSTR()` directly:

```
INSERT INTO MSGG_USER (USERNAME)
SELECT SUBSTR(GIVEN_NAME, 1, 1) || SURNAME;
```

Off the top of my head, it looks as though you might have been trying to alias the substring call with `GIVEN_NAME`.  In any case, you would not need any aliases in your select statement, as the columns are directly feeding into an insert operation.

**Edit:**

If you want to insert the first initial and last name in all lowercase, you can try wrapping these terms in `LOWER`:

```
INSERT INTO MSGG_USER (USERNAME)
SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(GIVEN_NAME, 1, 1)) || LOWER(SURNAME);
```

Comment: how to insert the above selected columns in lower case ?

Comment: INSERT INTO MSGG_USER (USERNAME,PASSWORD)
 SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(GIVEN_NAME,1,1) ||SURNAME, 
 UPPER(substr(GIVEN_NAME,1,1) ||SURNAME ||'_PASS'
 FROM MSGG_PEOPLE;   how to do two column insert as it gives me missing value error. thanks

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis there.  But if you need help with a different query you should open a new question.